# Is there a way to register or record the changes made in the database with Django?

Tags: mysql, django

I'm using MySQL as database for this app and I need to register or keep the record of all the changes made in one field of my User Model.

For example, every ten minutes I have a bot asking to an API some fields and everytime it PATCH the date field inside User Model. I need to keep record of that minute everytime it changes.

Comment: use a trigger when it upoates and inside the trigger insert information to your log table

Comment: You could use the ``post_save`` signal to log the changes in a custom Model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save

Comment: @Pedro - that would record that a change has occurred, not what it was.  The post-save hook doesn't offer a way to capture the previous state, so you can't see what has changed.  (Indeed, technically you only know that a save occurred.  The save could actually have made no change to the DB state.)

Comment: @StephenC You are right, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are several apps that can help you achieve what you want.

If what you need is to maintain the history of changes to you model the I think that this [Django Simple History](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is a good choice.

If you need to recover your model to a point in time, like a version control, then you could use [Django Reversion Docs](https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#).